# Change the color of a Google Form response when printing

Tags: google-forms

The text color of a Google Form response is very pale when I try to print an individual response.  (See the word John Doughnut in the second picture)

How can I darken it or change its color?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is an easy way to do this using the `Inspect` element on your browser**.

During the following 4 steps we will make use of [Inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/) at Google Chrome.
A similar approach will work for other browsers (Firefox, Explorer).

#### Step 1

Once you decide which individual answer you want to print out, you `right-click` on the element of the page (e.g. TEST LAST NAME) and select `Inspect` from the pop-out menu.

[image: inspect]

#### Step 2

This will bring up the Chrome DevTools Elements panel.
On the `Styles` tab you find `color` of the element in question.
The last identifier (`0.26`), represents the opacity of the element. You click once on `rgba(0,0,0,0.26)`.

[image: devtools]

#### Step 3

You change the opacity to `0.99` and click <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You can alternatively change it to `1` resulting to `rgba(0,0,0,1)`.

[image: opacity change]

#### Step 4

You can now print your document.

[image: print page]

---

#### EXTRA STEPS (to alter the color of the elements).

To change the color instead of clicking on `rgba(0,0,0,0.26)` you click once on the little colored square.
This action opens the `color picker`.

[image: the colors square]

When the dialog pops up, you make your changes and click  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to finalize your selection.

[image: color change]

You can now print your document using **the brand new colors**.

[image: print colors]

Using the above technique **you can alter other elements as well**.
Like changing the color of the answers submitted.

[image: other elements]

---

**One great advantage** of the above method is that your **alterations remain while you move back and forth** (as long as you use the arrow keys on the right hand side of the screen) as to print the other answers as well.

[image: using the arrow keys]